# Timezone field not working in Ner_Duckling

Tags: rasa-nlu, duckling

I am trying to use ner_duckling in rasa_nlu and unable to change time zone. By-default, it is giving output on the basis of UTC-timezone while I need output on the basis of IST timezone. Please let me know how can i change it from UTC to IST.

I am using ner_duckling in pipeline as:

```
- name: "ner_duckling"
  dimensions: ["time"]
  timezone: "Asia/India"
  locale: "en_GB"
```

https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/master/entities/

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the [Duckling documentation](https://duckling.wit.ai/#introduction) and it says:

> Timezones are parsed, but they don’t impact the time value (will be fixed shortly).

So, I guess you have to convert these time values yourself.
You could do this by using [custom actions](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions).